# Are there non-obvious finite $E_\infty$ ring spectra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, ring-spectra

I see two "obvious" classes of nonzero finite $E_\infty$ ring spectra $R$:

- $R = \Sigma^\infty_+ (S^1)^{\times n}$
- $R = D\Sigma^\infty_+ X$ ($X$ a finite space)

**Questions:**

1. Are there any others?
2. In all the above examples, the unit map $\mathbb S \to R$ splits off. Is this always the case?
3. In the second class of examples, I believe all elements of $\pi_\ast R$ not in the image of the unit $\pi_\ast \mathbb S \to \pi_\ast R$ are nilpotent. How generally is this true? Is it true for all examples not in the first class of examples?
4. How does the answer change if we localize at a prime, or perform some more drastic localization?

Comment: Well, as an obvious generalization of your first example there's $R=\mathbb{S}[G]$ for $G$ a compact Lie group (or more generally, a stably dualizable topological group).

Comment: G has to be abelian to get an E_infty thing (as opposed to an E_1 thing).

Comment: Another class of examples are square zero extensions by finite complexes.

Comment: Also, the unit map does not split off if X is empty.

Comment: @DylanWilson Duh... sorry. But at least this includes also finite commutative groups :)

Comment: Good point! Also, regarding nilpotence: by Mathew-Naumann-Noel, nilpotence is detected in integral homology; if R is finite then every element in nonzero degree is automatically nilpotent in homology so the same is true in homotopy. So the only thing that could go wrong is stuff in degree zero- and indeed that can happen. For example, take X to be disconnected and use a component to define an idempotent. (Note your claim in Question 3 is not quite right because of this example- the unit won’t hit this idempotent).

Comment: I suppose finite $E_\infty$ ring spectra are closed under smash product too. @DylanWilson The square-zero extensions are a great source of examples -- but to be careful on the splitting question, do you actually know an example of a finite square-zero extension of a finite $E_\infty$ ring spectrum which is not split? And thanks for clarifying the nilpotence question.

Comment: Square zero extensions off the sphere are all trivial (though most trivial sq zero extensions are not covered by your two examples). I bet there are lots of nontrivial 2-step extensions though.

Comment: (This is unrelated to the “splitting” question in your post though. ‘Split square zero’ is different than ‘unit splits off’; the unit will always split off of examples built this way).

Comment: Does Mandell's theorem imply that after $p$ completion, all examples are of type #2?

Comment: We can generalize from the unpointed suspension spectrum of a commutative product group to the pointed suspension spectrum of a smash commutative monoid. That captures the square zero extensions of the sphere spectrum. What connective examples does it miss?

Comment: We can twist together the connective and coconnective(?) examples. Consider a bundle of commutative groups over X. Then instead of maps from X into the sphere, consider sections from X into the sheaf of group rings. Commutative groups only allow discrete monodromy, but smash monoids (eg, with zero multiplication) allow more interesting twisting.

Comment: @BenWieland neat ideas! Note that the dual of a finite spectrum is again a finite spectrum, and thus it is bounded below and I think unbounded above unless it's zero -- so there's not really anything coconnective going on (although the homology gets flipped around if we have a manifold I suppose). In your first comment, I think you're saying that if $X$ is a finite spectrum, then the square-zero $E_\infty$ ring spectrum $\mathbb S \vee X$ is the suspension spectrum of a finite $E_\infty$ object in $(Top_\ast, \wedge)$ -- could you explain this? In your second comment, why is the result finite?

Comment: "Coconnective" is wrong, but if the question were $E_\infty$ $\mathbb Z$-algebras, construction 2 would be. It seems like there is something useful to be said about objects such that when they are smashed with Z become coconnective... A monoid for the smash product is a monoid with a point that absorbs all other points; $X_+$ is a smash monoid where the product of any two elements is the basepoint... Section spaces satisfy Mayer-Vietoris, which reduces the question of finiteness to finiteness over cells, which is the usual statement that the dual of finite is finite.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Interesting point... I think the relevant version of Mandell's theorem says that an $E_\infty$ $H\bar F_p$-algebra is of the form $D\Sigma^\infty_+ X \wedge H\bar F_p$ for $X$ finite and simply-connected if and only if the obvious conditions on homotopy are met and the power operation $P^0$ acts injectively. But even if we have such an equivalence $R \wedge H\bar F_p \to D\Sigma^\infty_+X \wedge H\bar F_p$, I think this map need not exist _before_ smashing with $H\bar F_p$, so there need not be an equivalence of $p$-completions as far as I can see. Still, it's something!

Comment: @BenWieland Thanks. I'm still confused by the multiplication on $X_+$ -- what's the unit? It seems to me that the only option is the basepoint $\ast$, but then the product $\ast x y z$ seems like it has to be $x$, $y$, and $z$ simultaneously if this multiplication is commutative and associative -- so it doesn't look well-defined to me.

Comment: Oh, yeah, $X_+$ is a nonunital monoid. We should stick with unital ones. But $X_{++}$ is a unital monoid, so its reduced suspension is the unreduced suspension of $X_+$, often called $S+X$.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is a finite of type $n \geq 1$, then $L_{T(n)} X$ is $H\mathbb Q$-acyclic. If $X$ is $E_\infty$, then $L_{T(n)} X$ is $E_\infty$. But an $E_\infty$ ring spectrum which is $H\mathbb Q$-acyclic must vanish. So if $X$ is a finite $E_\infty$ ring spectrum, then $X$ must have type $0$.